# How to customize wordpress theme, include widgets?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a new site with a Wordpress theme (and I failed to find any information about the theme). The theme have all the features I need - forms, sliders, google map widget and others. But I see no tools to change them, except manually editing theme's php files (I've already done child theme). I can do it, but I'm doubt if this is the right way to create sites with Wordpress? 
Please give me a hint, what should I do - edit php files, create new menus and content pages (which already are in theme) or maybe something else?
PS: sorry for possible stupid or duplicated question in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I normaly edit the themes by changing the php files.

U can use a plugin for editing your themes. I use this one https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-editor/.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.